# My Quicksort does not sort the input array

Tags: c++

I tried to write quicksort by myself and faced with problem that my algorithm doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void swap(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

void qsort(vector <int> a, int first, int last)
{
    int f = first, l = last;
    int mid = a[(f + l) / 2];
     
    do {
        while (a[f] < mid) {
            f++;
        }
        while (a[l] > mid) {
            l--;
        }

        if (f <= l) {
            swap(a[f], a[l]);
            f++;
            l--;
        }
    } while (f < l);

    if (first < l) {
        qsort(a, first, l);
    }
    if (f < last) {
        qsort(a, f, last);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> a;
    a.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    qsort(a, 0, n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My sort is similar to other that described on the Internet and I can't find where I made a mistake.
Even when I change sort function, the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass `qsort` the array you want to sort, you pass it the *value* of that array. It modifies the value that was passed to it, but that has no effect on the array.

Imagine if you had this code:

```
 void foo(int a)
 {
     a = a + 1;
 }
```

Do you think if I call this like this `foo(4);` that `foo` is somehow going to turn that `4` into a `5`? No. It's going to take the *value* 4 and turn it into the value *5* and then throw it away, since I didn't do anything with the modified value. Similarly:

```
int f = 4;
foo(f);
```

This will pass the *value* 4 to `foo`, which will increment it and then throw the incremented value away. The value `f` has after this will still be 4 since nothing ever changed `f`.

You meant this:

```
void qsort(vector <int>& a, int first, int last)
```

Your `swap` has the same problem. It swaps the values of `a` and `b`, but then never does anything with the value of `a` or `b`. So it has no effect. How could it? Would `swap(3, 4);` somehow change that `3` into a `4` and vice-versa? What would that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your `swap` does not swap anything. You should write tests not only for the whole program but for as small pieces as possible. At least you should test single functions. Try this:

```
 int main() {
     int a= 42;
     int b= 0;
     std::cout << "before " << a << " " << b << "\n";
     swap(a,b);
     std::cout << "after " << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

This is "poor mans testing". For automated tests you should use a testing framework.

Then read about pass by reference. (While doing so you hopefully also realize the issue with not passing the vector to `qsort` by reference.)

Then use `std::swap` instead of reinventing a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I Found two error on your code
 `void swap(int a, int b)` This method is not working, cause is receive value only and swap , but the original one is not updated.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int t;

   t  = *b;
   *b = *a;
   *a = t;
}

swap(&a, &b);
```

And you pass vactor which also pass value. replace your `void qsort(vector <int> &a, int first, int last)` method.

Comment: Your swapping function is a C-like way for passing by reference.